# NGINX Config for seafile on subdomain

Tags: nginx

I just deployed a seafile server on my home server. The deployment of seafile was successfully and I got no errors. So I tried to setup nginx.

My nginx config:

```
server {
        root         /var/www/mydomain;
        index        index.html;
        server_name  mydomain.de
        return       301 mydomain.de$request_uri;
}

server {
        root         /var/www/mydomain;
        index        index.html;
        server_name  http://www.mydomain.de;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.cloud.mydomain.de;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param    SERVER_PROTOCOL        $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param    SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
fastcgi_param    SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
    }

    location /seafhttp {
        rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
        proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
        proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
    }

    location /media {
        root /home/myuser/seafile/seafile-server-latest/seahub;
    }
}
```

my ccnet.conf:

```
SERVICE_URL = http://www.cloud.mydomain.de
```

seahub_settings.py (last line):

```
FILE_SERVER_ROOT = 'http://www.cloud.mydomain.de/seafhttp'
```

The first two server blocks working fine and as expected. But when I try to visit www.cloud.mydomain.de I just get an blank page (redirect to www.cloud.mydomain.de/defaultsite)

```
http://www.cloud.mydomain.de/ => redirect to /defaultsite (cause of domain hoster?) and blank page
http://www.cloud.mydomain.de/seafhttp => blank page
http://www.cloud.mydomain.de/media => blank page
```

I although made sure that the seafile server is running by:

```
./seafile.sh start
./seahub.sh start-fastcgi
```

Any suggestions what could possibly solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

`server_name  http://www.mydomain.de;` is not correct.

Only the domain name is added to the `server_name` directive, protocol is not included.

Also, the first `server` block doesn't have a semicolon on the `server_name` line, so it shouldn't work either.

Actually those two first `server` blocks make no sense. The first block configures a `301` redirect that doesn't include the protocol for the redirect. `return` directive has to include the protocol.

Are you sure that the DNS for `www.cloud.mydomain.de` has been correctly configured?